# django values_list of all fields in foreign key

Tags: python, django

i have a class with a foreign key to another class:

```
class MyEvent(models.Model): 
    msg = models.ForeignKey(MyMessage)  
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENTS_TYPES)

class MyMessage(models.Model): 
    notification = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENTS_TYPES2)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
```

the result of:

```
MyEvent.objects.all().values('msg','event_type')
```

is:

```
[{'msg': 18L,'event_type': 1L}, {'msg': 15L,'event_type': 2L}]
```

but is it possible to get all values of the foreign key (MyMessage) object also? ( i want to get without explicit reference. - not like adding 'msg__description' to MyEvent.objects.all().values('msg','event_type'))

the result that i want is something like:

```
[{'msg': 18L,'msg__name': 'dd','msg__description': 'kkk','event_type': 1L}, {'msg': 15L,'msg__name': 'dd','msg__description': 'kkk','event_type': 2L}]
```

Answer (score 20):

You can reference foreign key attributes in values function:

```
MyEvent.objects.all().values('msg','event_type', 'msg__name', 'msg__description')
```

Comment: yes i know that, i want to get without explicit reference. (if in the future the foreign object will change - add more fields- then i want t get them also)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list of field names with `msg__` prepended to each value using list comprehension based on `MyMessage._meta`. Then simply unpack the values using `.values(*list_of_fields)`.

Other than that, it is not possible. `values()` only accepts field names as positional arguments, so you'll have to implicitly generate the arguments before calling `values()`.

Comment: Does anyone have a clearer example of how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You should add related name to foreign key like this

```
class MyEvent(models.Model): 
    msg = models.ForeignKey(MyMessage,related_name='message')  
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENTS_TYPES)

class MyMessage(models.Model): 
    notification = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENTS_TYPES2)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False) 
    related_name=description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
```

Then you can retrieve it with related name. like this:

```
objs=MyEvent.objects.all()
objs[0].message.all() # this is the Mymessage record
```

then you can create your list whatever you like