# How to extract the string or name of all foreign keys used in a model in django-pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-pandas

I have data stored in a Django `Model/Table` which I am fetching in pandas dataframe via `django-pandas (Version: 0.6.6)`

The model has 3 columns as foreign key viz: `state_name, district_name and block_name`

The model.py is as:

```
####################################################################################

BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
UNIT_CATEGORIES = (('AMFU', 'AMFU'), ('DAMU', 'DAMU'))
  
class GroupDetail(models.Model):
    """Village level Whatsapp Information options"""

    unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=UNIT_CATEGORIES, default="DAMU")
    state_name = models.ForeignKey(State, to_field='state_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="KVK")
    district_name = models.ForeignKey(District, to_field='district_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    block_name = models.ForeignKey(Block, to_field='block_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    village_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    village_covered_through_whatsapp_group = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Village Covered through Whatsapp Group "yes/no"'), choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    number_of_whatsapp_group_created = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])

    objects = DataFrameManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group_Info_Table'
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["state_name","district_name", "block_name", "village_name"], name="all_keys_unique_together")]



    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit_type
        return self.state_name
        return self.unit_name
        return self.district_name
        return self.block_name
        return self.village_name
        return self.village_covered_through_whatsapp_group
        return self.number_of_whatsapp_group_created
        return self.number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village
```

views.py is as:

**Case 1:**
PS: kindly look at string of column name passed : `state_name__id`

If I am fetching data like this, it returns `id's` of all columns having `foreign keys`

```
def amfu_state_wise(request):

    state_name_is = None 
    district_name_is = None 
    block_name_is = None 
    if request.method == "POST":
        state_name_is=request.POST.get('state')
        district_name_is=request.POST.get('district')
        block_name_is=request.POST.get('block')

    fetch_whole_database = GroupDetail.objects.all()

    all_fields = GroupDetail._meta.get_fields()
    print("all_fields",all_fields)

    fetch_data_df = fetch_whole_database.to_dataframe(['unit_type', 'state_name__id', 'unit_name', 'district_name__id', 'block_name__id', 'village_name', 'village_covered_through_whatsapp_group', 'number_of_whatsapp_group_created', 'number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village'], index='id')

    print("fetch_data_df", fetch_data_df.state_name__id.head(5))
```

The output in console is as

```
all_fields id
31618    11
31619    11
31620    11
31621    11
31622    11
Name: state_name__id, dtype: int64
[15/Jun/2022 12:37:36] "GET /damuwhatsapp/amfu_state_wise HTTP/1.1" 200 16811
```

**Case 2:**

But when I filter all object of model, it returens NaN value

PS: kindly look at string of column name passed : `state_name__name`

```
def amfu_state_wise(request):

    state_name_is = None 
    district_name_is = None 
    block_name_is = None 
    if request.method == "POST":
        state_name_is=request.POST.get('state')
        district_name_is=request.POST.get('district')
        block_name_is=request.POST.get('block')

    fetch_whole_database = GroupDetail.objects.filter().values().all()

    all_fields = GroupDetail._meta.get_fields()
    print("all_fields",all_fields)

    fetch_data_df = fetch_whole_database.to_dataframe(['unit_type', 'state_name__name', 'unit_name', 'district_name__id', 'block_name__id', 'village_name', 'village_covered_through_whatsapp_group', 'number_of_whatsapp_group_created', 'number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village'], index='id')

    print("fetch_data_df", fetch_data_df.state_name__name.head(5))
```

The output in console is as

```
all_fields id
31618   NaN
31619   NaN
31620   NaN
31621   NaN
31622   NaN
Name: state_name__name, dtype: float64
[15/Jun/2022 12:44:24] "GET /damuwhatsapp/amfu_state_wise HTTP/1.1" 200 16811
```

**Case 3:**

But when I use
`fetch_whole_database = GroupDetail.objects.filter.all()`
or
`fetch_whole_database = GroupDetail.objects.all()`

PS: kindly look at string of column name passed : `state_name`

```
def amfu_state_wise(request):

    state_name_is = None 
    district_name_is = None 
    block_name_is = None 
    if request.method == "POST":
        state_name_is=request.POST.get('state')
        district_name_is=request.POST.get('district')
        block_name_is=request.POST.get('block')

    fetch_whole_database = GroupDetail.objects.filter.all()


    all_fields = GroupDetail._meta.get_fields()
    print("all_fields",all_fields)

    fetch_data_df = fetch_whole_database.to_dataframe(['unit_type', 'state_name', 'unit_name', 'district_name__id', 'block_name__id', 'village_name', 'village_covered_through_whatsapp_group', 'number_of_whatsapp_group_created', 'number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village'], index='id')

    print("fetch_data_df", fetch_data_df.state_name.head(5))
```

The foreign key string `HARYANA` is returned with error as :

```
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1273, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 275, in get_prep_lookup
    rhs_value = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(rhs_value)
  File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'HARYANA'.
[15/Jun/2022 13:18:35] "GET /damuwhatsapp/amfu_state_wise HTTP/1.1" 500 159434
```

So how to get the string of all columns with foreign keys in django-pandas Dataframe?

Comment: `GroupDetail.objects.filter().values().all()` will return a list of [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) which don't have access to model instance so it'll not perform lookups

Comment: Okay, What are alternate options to fetch the sting of specific or all column @AnkitTiwari ?

Comment: Try to remove `.values()` so it shold look like this `GroupDetail.objects.filter()`

Comment: Note: Only the first `return` statement in the `__str__` method in the model will run, this means that `__str__` will return `self.unit_type`, the rest will be ignored.

Comment: @麻美雫  can I specifically get the list of all string of any specific column? if it is possible then I can extract the specific columns then build the whole dataframe later by merging columns.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari That did not worked Ankit. However, I have updated the question. Kindly have a look

Comment: *`ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'HARYANA'.`* - as you see it says somewhere in your code it want id(int) but you've provided string check your lookups i think you've to pass `state_name__id` instead of `'state_name'`

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635511/django-values-list-of-all-fields-in-foreign-key) might solve your problem.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari, I got the ID in Case 1, But I need its string, instead of its ID. That's what the question is all about.

Comment: @麻美雫 Will give it a try.

Comment: This worked finally. ```fetch_data_from_whole_database = pd.DataFrame.from_records(GroupDetail.objects.all().values('id', 'unit_type','state_name', 'unit_name', 'district_name', 'block_name', 'village_name','village_covered_through_whatsapp_group', 'number_of_whatsapp_group_created', 'number_of_farmers_covered_in_the_village'))```